# AVPlayer with FullScreen - iOS

Tags: ios

I have created instance of AVPlayer and playing content in it. I need to provide one option to show this movie in full screen. Does any other option present instead of creating instance of AVPlayerController and using native playback button options.

Comment: No, U have to create an instance of AVPlayerController.

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer is containing only video view. Buttons and basically all the UI over the video are responsibility of developer.

So you need to do view controller that have view where AVPLayer will be embedded, and over it another views (like buttons, labels). And of course rig everything with constraints. When you tap "full screen" button, animate constraints so you resize your video. This is it.

Much simpler (considering lines of code that must be written) is to use AVPLayerViewController, but you loose possibility of custom UI. On other hand most of the logic is there. (except for support HLS EVENT type playlists that are not closed, there is a bug that will be fixed in iOS11)

**Update:**
Bug in AVPLayerViewController, regarding HLS EVENT type is fixed in iOS11.